# Is it fine to use tail -f on large log files

Tags: logs, monitoring, tail

I would like monitor a large log file (close to 1 GB) for errors. I want this to be close to real time (few seconds delay is fine). My plan is to use `tail -f | grep`. Is there any performance issues with using such a method when running it over a long time, say from zero bytes to 1 GB? Are there any standards practices used for such a monitoring. Note that I would like to do this using standard unix commands available on Solaris 10.

If that is possible, my file even rolls over and I have one more problem to sort out :). using `tail -F` (`--follow=name`) is not an option for me because `-F` is not supported in the server I want to run this on. My plan is to use a script which will start this tail and poll on to find if the file is rolled over. If yes, then kill the tail and restart it. Any better approach?

Comment: You mean "kill the `tail`", right?

Comment: Yes, "kill tail", not find. Thanks, edited the question

Comment: If a 2 GB sized of file does not contain a new line character, how does tail work?

Answer (score 6):

On my linux system (GNU coreutils 8.12), I was able to check (using `strace`) that `tail -f`¹ uses the `lseek` system call to skip over most of the file quickly:

```
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 194086
lseek(3, 188416, SEEK_SET)              = 188416
```

This means that the size of the tracked file should not matter in anyway.

Maybe you can check if the same applies on your system. (Obviously, it should be the case.)

—
<sup>1. I also tried disabling inotify support with the undocumented `---disable-inotify`, just in case.</sup>

Comment: Real Men read the source (:

Comment: @Gilles. I can't teach the OP (or the reader) how to read the source if he doesn't know already. A lot easier to tell him to use `strace` ;)

Comment: Actually, on a system where `tail -F` is not supported, chances are that `strace` is not available…

Comment: `truss` is the corresponding utility on Solaris.

Comment: and it shows similar seek calls. llseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR) = 0, llseek(0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFF5FFF6, SEEK_END) = 7923269

Answer (score 5):

If it's invoked on a regular file (as opposed to a pipe), both GNU tail and OpenBSD tail (unless called with `-n +N`) seek to the end of the file, then works backwards to find the line where it should start printing. I don't know if Solaris does the same, but it's a reasonable approach, so I expect most unices to do the same. Therefore the size of the file is irrelevant for performance.

Answer (score 2):

I do this every day.  I generally scan a dozen or so logs on our test and production servers using `tail -f logs/*.{log,err,out}`.  The initial load is a bit much (depending on the number of files globbed), but after that, streaming is real-time.

Instead of sending to grep, I use the `exec` functionality in `screen` since I want to generally see all the output (for full tracebacks and messages related to the issue).  For example,

```
!:sed -n s/.*Exception.*/\007/p
```

To cause the terminal to beep (or flash) whenever the word Exception is found.